# PHP request type Post

Tags: php, http-post, httprequest

I came across this function in VB, can someone help me to convert this in PHP.
And how do I parse a certain value like API KEY into http headers? say like the API_KEY variable.

Thanks a lot...

```
Dim request = TryCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("https://domain.com/getticker"), 

System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
request.Method = "POST"
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
request.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
Using writer = New System.IO.StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream())
  Dim byteArray As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("timestamp=1387132060")
  request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
  writer.Write(byteArray)
  writer.Close()
End Using
Dim responseContent As String
Using response = TryCast(request.GetResponse(), System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
  Using reader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
    responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd()
  End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Start from here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php; http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php

Comment: thank you for the direction. It is spot on.